# CSS trick to make page intact when overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

When I have a scrollbar on my page and I apply `overflow:hidden`, it hides the scrollbar, but the page moves to the side by a few pixels. I would like it to stay intact. I tried to apply `position:absolute` and `left:10px`, but it didn't work.

Any ideas on how to make it stay intact?

basically, all of this is done for the modal dialogs to appear with the main page content including scrollbars locked so the user can only scroll the modal dialog.

the browser I try this in is older IE versions and the code for opening the dialog is this:

```
 if ((ua.msie && ua.version.slice(0, 3) == "7.0") || (ua.msie && ua.version.slice(0, 3) == "6.0")) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('html').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
}
```

Everything works perfect except that the page content moves to the right side a little bit when the scrollbar gets hidden.

Comment: Could you add your html and css code ? Even better, a http://fiddle.jshell.net/. Thanks

Comment: @Jean-Charles Who stole http://jsfiddle.net and cloned it on another domain? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add some `padding` to the `body` or the main content `div`.

Something like

```
body{
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be 15px in Chrome.